# Exclude certain actions from animating in a UIView animation block?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewanimation

I have some code that needs to run inside `UIView` animation brackets, but I want it be exempt from being animated, so all the code on either side of it is animated but it isn't. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is this "exempt" code UI related? Does it need to run at a certain time in the animation?

Comment: Yes, it does, and is UI related.

Comment: not sure why this has been downvoted as it seems like a pretty reasonable question

Comment: -1 because it would have been easy for you to explain what you're really trying to accomplish, but instead we're left guessing why (and if) this is really necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't code that you can just insert into a UIView animation block to exclude it from animation, but you can nest UIView animation and completion blocks for arbitrarily complicated animation chains:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^ {
    // Animation Code.
} completion: ^ (BOOL finished) {
    // Non-animated code, executed after first animation block...
    // Blah;
    // [Blah blah];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^ {
        // More animation code.
    }];
}];
```

Comment: It's running a method in a different class and i'd rather not split that method up into 3 sections just to get this to work.

Comment: @Andrew, there's nothing stopping you from sending messages to other classes in that code. Maybe you ought to post your code so it's easier to understand your specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the way:

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    view.frame = CGRectMake(...);
}];
```

Comment: If you want to make changes to your view within an animation block but exclude those changes from being animates you just wrap the changes you want excluded in a UIView.performWithoutAnimation code block.